# JavaFx: Transiction

Tags: javafx

Hello I am trying to make a transition but I am having difficulty with positioning if I would use the left would be much easier but I am doubtful about setToX

i want make this:

[image]

I made it

[image]

i have some problems when i open the screen my menu 2 is not off stage even though i have set it on translateX off screen
And when I open a white bar appears

I wanted to open the second menu and it would just show the icon and not icon and text

my main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class);
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("scene.fxml"));

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class backup {

    @FXML
    private VBox toolBar;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton teste;

    @FXML
    private VBox subMenu;

    public void initialize() {
        TranslateTransition openNav = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(350), subMenu);
        openNav.setToX(subMenu.getWidth());
        TranslateTransition closeNav = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(350), subMenu);

        teste.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) -> {
            if(subMenu.getTranslateX() == 70){
                openNav.play();
            }else{
                closeNav.setToX(subMenu.getWidth());
                closeNav.play();
            }
        });
    }
```

fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.semeq.controllers.home.backup">
   <children>
      <VBox fx:id="toolBar" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: #e548;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <JFXButton fx:id="teste" accessibleText="Gerenciar" buttonType="RAISED" focusTraversable="false" pickOnBounds="false" ripplerFill="WHITE" text="Gerenciar">
               <graphic>
                  <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" size="25" />
               </graphic>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton accessibleText="Gerenciar2" buttonType="RAISED" focusTraversable="false" ripplerFill="WHITE" text="Gerenciar">
               <graphic>
                  <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" size="25" />
               </graphic>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton accessibleText="Gerenciar3" buttonType="RAISED" focusTraversable="false" ripplerFill="WHITE" text="Gerenciar">
               <graphic>
                  <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" size="25" />
               </graphic>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton accessibleText="Gerenciar4" buttonType="RAISED" focusTraversable="false" ripplerFill="WHITE" text="Gerenciar">
               <graphic>
                  <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" size="25" />
               </graphic>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <VBox fx:id="subMenu" layoutX="30.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="65.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000;" translateX="70.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. As you were already advised to do in all your previous questions - when do you intend to follow them?

Comment: I asked the question trying to follow there explain my problem showed the parts of the code sent photos and etc.

Comment: What is missing?

Comment: I have a problem with making a transition is appearing a soft background when opening, and I described it really I don't know where I went wrong ..

Comment: the idea of a [mcve] is that anybody can copy it, throw it into her IDE and reproduce it .. which even might be possible, but it's no _minimal_ - or does it pose a problem only with a SpringApplication?

Comment: Ok I'll repost the full code of all classes
sorry i thought i was correct as i tried to explain to the max with photo and gif

Comment: nonono ... mind the _M_ - rarely anybody wants to wade through tons of code! so not everything, not your real production code, but an example that's stripped down so far that is demonstrates the problem (and contains nothing unrelated)

Comment: but I put as little code as possible and just related to the problem

Comment: yeah, nearly - but repeating: why the SpringApplication? That's most probably unrelated to your problem, so remove it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- You retrieve the width before the first layout pass on the scene. At that time the width is `0`.
- The horizontal position of the menu is detemined by both `layoutX` and `translateX` complicating things a bit
- Your layout is non-responsive. Any resizing of the window (or the menu) breaks the layout.
- You use 2 animations; there's nothing wrong with that, but simply playing an animation backwards allows you to simplify things like hiding the menu while it's moving into view.

My recommendation would be to add your own property and animate it using `Timeline`.

The following example also replaces the `AnchorPane` with a `StackPane` since it's easier to specify the position there. Furthermore it keeps a part of the menu in view and expanding it is triggered by hovering this area. You could easily remove this by removing `.subtract(hoverAreaWidth)` in the binding for `translateX`.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final double hoverAreaWidth = 20; // part that is still shown when collapsed

    Region child = new Region(); // some other child
    child.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-background-insets: 3;"); // show some border

    Region menu = new Region();
    menu.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
    menu.setPrefWidth(200);
    menu.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

    DoubleProperty visibleFraction = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    menu.translateXProperty().bind(Bindings.subtract(1d, visibleFraction).multiply(menu.widthProperty().subtract(hoverAreaWidth)));

    StackPane container = new StackPane(child, menu);
    container.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    // menu is right-aligned
    // the menu can be shown/hidden by setting it's translateX property
    // to values between 0 (fully visible) and its width (completely hidden)
    StackPane.setAlignment(menu, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

    // make sure the part of the menu always shown does not cover the other child
    // can be removed for hoverAreaWidth = 0
    final Insets margin = new Insets(0, hoverAreaWidth, 0, 0);
    StackPane.setMargin(child, margin);

    Timeline animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(visibleFraction, 0d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(350), new KeyValue(visibleFraction, 1d)));

    menu.hoverProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        animation.setRate(newValue ? 1 : -1);
        if (animation.getStatus() != Status.RUNNING) {
            animation.play();
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(container, 400, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: I got bro thank you very much
could you ask me a question? I wish nothing of the menu would appear I would have to do this:

Comment: As mentioned you can change the line creating the binding to `menu.translateXProperty().bind(Bindings.subtract(1d, visibleFraction).multiply(menu.widthProperty()));` and remove the part with the margin.

Comment: yes sorry i made this but  i have problem to open with click button  u can help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57512941/javafx-animation-transiction